# adding significance brackets to ridgeline plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a ridge plot to compare a few groups (using [ggridges](https://wilkelab.org/ggridges/articles/introduction.html) package) and would like to add significance brackets to show comparisons between some group levels (using [ggsignif](https://wilkelab.org/ggridges/articles/introduction.html) package).

But this doesn't seem to work because the computation fails in `stat_ggsignif`.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
set.seed(123)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggridges)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) +
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 1) +
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("setosa", "versicolor")))
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181
#> Warning in f(..., self = self): NAs introduced by coercion
#> Warning: Computation failed in `stat_signif()`:
#> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

How can I get these two packages to work with each other? Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @ventrilocus that ggridges might not be the appropriate package. Check  `gghalves::geom_half_violin` and/or `see::geom_violinhalf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not manage to combine A) geom_density_ridges and B) geom_signif. The reason is that (A) requires numerical variable as x and categories as y, while (B) requires numerical variable as y and categories as x. And I have not managed to overwrite this behaviour.
But I assume that you have chosen ridge_plots over simple boxplots as you are interested in a more informative visualization of the distribution. To do so, there is a much better solution than ridge_plots, the so called violin plots. See below a standard boxplot (with labelled significance):

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("setosa", "versicolor")), test = "t.test")
```

[image]

See below a violin plot (with jitter and labelled significance):

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_violin(trim = F) + geom_jitter() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("setosa", "versicolor")), test = "t.test")
```

[image]

This does the job unless you are particularly interest in making ggridges and ggsignif work together. Please note that a violin plot is just a folded density plot (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot#:~:text=A%20violin%20plot%20is%20a,by%20a%20kernel%20density%20estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot#:%7E:text=A%20violin%20plot%20is%20a,by%20a%20kernel%20density%20estimator) for more details).

For the same purpose, see also the sina plot (suggestion by tjebo):

```
library(ggforce)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_sina() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("setosa", "versicolor")), test = "t.test")
```

[image]

Comment: If you're looking to combine jitter and violin plot, there is maybe a slicker solution to that - the ["Sina plot"](https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/boxplots-violins.html#fig:lincoln-temp-sina). check `ggforce::geom_sina`, or very similar in nature,  `ggbeeswarm::geom_quasirandom`

Comment: Nice suggestion. I have added it to the answer

Comment: @Ventrilocus Thanks for the detailed reply! I am going to wait for a day or so and then accept your answer if there aren't any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a new pull request to `ggsignif`, the following now works:

```r
set.seed(123)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggridges)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) +
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 1) +
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("setosa", "versicolor")),
              y_position = 9)
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>